# How to link two page models in wagtail with a many-to-many relation using an InlinePanel

Tags: wagtail

I want two link two page models, `method` and `instrument`. On the page showing the `method`, there should be a region showing related `instrument`s and vice versa. The Wagtail 1.9 documentation shows a simple implementation of many-to-many fields for categories ([Docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/getting_started/tutorial.html#categories)), but since the number of `method`s and `instrument`s is quite large, I'd like to implement this with an `InlinePanel` in the admin interface. The examples for categories defines the field within the page-model, but this does not allow for using an `InlinePanel`, does it?

Furthermore, it would be extremly helpful if the relation of `instrument` to `method` could be edited from the admin-interface of a `method` model as well as from the interface of an `instrument` model.

For Wagtail < 1.9 I would try to solve this using a snippet with two `ForeignKeys`, but I think this is exactly what many-to-many relations have been implemented for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible - InlinePanels require the old ParentalKey-style relation, and won't work with a many-to-many relation.

> Furthermore, it would be extremly helpful if the relation of instrument to method could be edited from the admin-interface of a method model as well as from the interface of an instrument model.

This is also not supported, by design - all data must 'belong' to one page model or the other. Otherwise, you'd run into inconsistencies in the page editing workflow: if you update the relation on the `instrument` side but save your changes as draft rather than publishing them, is the change reflected on the `method` side, or not?